# How to view class labels after one hot encoding during training/testing and after the prediction in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from imutils import paths
from pathlib import path
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os


imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('D:/keras-cat-dog/dataset'))
data = []
labels = []


for imagePath in imagePaths:
  # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

# load the image, swap color channels, and resize it to be a fixed
# 224x224 pixels while ignoring aspect ratio
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

# update the data and labels lists, respectively
data.append(image)
labels.append(label)


# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays while scaling the pixel
# intensities to the range [0, 255]
data = np.array(data) / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)


# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)


# initialize the training data augmentation object
trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=15,
fill_mode="nearest")


# load the VGG16 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are left
# off
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))


# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 25
BS = 8

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])


# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit_generator(
    trainAug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)


# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)



imagePath_1 = os.path.normpath('D:/Classification-master/data_two_class/test/cat/NORMAL2-IM- 
1396-0001.jpeg')
label_1=imagePath_1.split(os.sep)[-2]
image_pred = cv2.imread(imagePath)
image_pred = cv2.cvtColor(image_pred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_pred = cv2.resize(image_pred, (224, 224))
img_pred = np.array(img_pred) / 255.0



rslt = model.predict(img_pred.reshape(1,224,224,3))
#decode_predictions(rslt)
```

I am using the code above to classify image using keras and tensorflow but I have a hard time understanding the labels for the prediction since I have done an one hot encoding on them and now when I am actually predicting a single image it is showing an array of two probabilities. After using the argmax function I am getting  a 0 or 1 and cant understand what it signifies.

```
In [209]: rslt
Out[209]: array([[0.9550967 , 0.04490325]], dtype=float32)

rslt = np.argmax(rslt)
Out[219]: 0
```

I'd be greatful if someone can show a way where I can see which class label is going to "0"/"1" during the encoding in the data processing phase and which class labels were present during the validation(testY) and the class label of the image has when I am predicting a single image.

Regards,

Subhra

Comment: Instead of all this (mostly irrelevant to the question) wall of code, please post a sample of 1) your initial `labels` 2) your `labels` after you have transformed them with `LabelBinarizer`. See how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Softmax** function outputs numbers that represent probabilities, each number's value is between 0 and 1 valid value range of probabilities. The range is denoted as [0,1] . The numbers are zero or positive. **The entire output vector sums to 1.**

**argmax** Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

So print your labels and understand what your first and second indices represent?

As you have used softmax in your final layer, it gives the probability of the image belonging to the different classes. In your case it is 2 classes thus it is showing probability of the image belonging to these two classes. If you sum your probabilities 0.9550967 and 0.04490325, it will sum up to 1.

```
0.9550967 + 0.04490325 = 1
```

`np.argmax(rslt)` returns the indices having maximum value.

**Here is an Example (1) -**
Print the labels and understand what the first and second indices represent -

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# define example
data = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']

values = np.array(data)

#Binary encode
lb = LabelBinarizer()

labels = lb.fit_transform(values)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
print("which position represents for cat and dog?:")
print("Data is:",data)
print(labels)
```

Output will be - **Here the first indice is for the cat and second is for dog.**

```
which position represents for cat and dog?:
Data is: ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Now lets understand **argmax** with your softmax `array([[0.9550967 , 0.04490325]]` values

**Example (2):** Will take your softmax output as it is.

```
import numpy as np
rslt = np.array([[0.9550967,0.04490325]])
rslt = np.argmax(rslt)
print(rslt)
```

Output should give 0 as the first indice has higher value. **So its Cat as per above Example (1).**

```
0
```

**Example (3):** Will swap your softmax output.

```
import numpy as np
rslt = np.array([[0.04490325,0.9550967]])
rslt = np.argmax(rslt)
print(rslt)
```

Output should give 1 as the second indice has higher value. **So its Dog as per above Example (1).**

```
1
```

Comment: @SUBHRA SANKHA - If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote it. Thank You.

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Happy Learning. Cheers.